# I want to fit the contents on Angular Dashboard so all contents appear without scrolling downwards

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, dashboard

I created an Angular Dashboards but somewhow I want that all contents should be displayed without scrolling downwards. Means it fits to the window.

On the screenshot you can see that half of the Angular Dashboard is cut off. I didn't find the right solution, so maybe one of you have good idea how to fix the problem.
[image]

Comment: you need to adjust the content. If you have provided fixed height then it is not going to work. Try to provide height to each component in %  or vh so that it will not go beyond 100.

Comment: an you give me an example? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take this simple example

```css
.parent{
  height:100vh;
  background:red;
  }
  
  .child1{
  height:50vh;
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    test
  </div>
    <div class="child1">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really helpfull. Using vh and vw for window height and width is really useful